How to recalculate pose bone rotations when armature bone rotation is changed?
I'm trying to import bones and animation data in to blender. The quaternions I have for each keyframe are correct if the armature's bones do not have any rotation. However I also need to import the armature bones to have their original rotations, making the keyframe quaternions no longer correct. I can't figure out what calculation I need to do to effectively reverse the rotation of the underlying bone.
To be clear this works but the underlying armature bones have no rotation:
armature_edit_bone.matrix = mathutils.Matrix.LocRotScale(imported_translation, None, None)


pose_bone.rotation_quaternion = imported_keyframe_quaternion

Ultimately what I need to do is this:
armature_edit_bone.matrix = mathutils.Matrix.LocRotScale(imported_translation, imported_rotation_quaternion, None)


pose_bone.rotation_quaternion = imported_keyframe_quaternion (some calculation here)

But it obviously doesn't work as it changes what the ultimate rotation is.
I would really appreciate some help with this.
I've added a minimum script that shows the problem:
import bpy
import math
import mathutils

def make_armature(rotation):
    armature = bpy.data.armatures.new(name="armature")
    armature_object = bpy.data.objects.new(name="armature", object_data=armature)
    
    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(armature_object)
    
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = armature_object
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    
    armature_bone = armature.edit_bones.new(name="bone")
    armature_bone.length = 1.0
    armature_bone.matrix = mathutils.Matrix.LocRotScale(None, rotation, None)
    
    armature_bone1 = armature.edit_bones.new(name="bone")
    armature_bone1.length = 1.0
    armature_bone1.matrix = mathutils.Matrix.LocRotScale((0.0, 0.0, 1.0), rotation, None)
    
    armature_bone1.parent = armature_bone
    
    armature_bone2 = armature.edit_bones.new(name="bone")
    armature_bone2.length = 1.0
    armature_bone2.matrix = mathutils.Matrix.LocRotScale((0.0, 0.0, 2.0), rotation, None)
    
    armature_bone2.parent = armature_bone1
    
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

    return armature_object

def pose(armature_object):
    armature_object.animation_data_create()
    action = bpy.data.actions.new(name="action")
    armature_object.animation_data.action = action
    
    armature_object.pose.bones[0].rotation_quaternion = mathutils.Quaternion((0.0, 0.0, 1.0), math.radians(90.0))
    armature_object.pose.bones[1].rotation_quaternion = mathutils.Quaternion((0.0, 1.0, 0.0), math.radians(90.0))
    armature_object.pose.bones[2].rotation_quaternion = mathutils.Quaternion((1.0, 0.0, 0.0), math.radians(90.0))

correct_pose_incorrect_bone_rotations = make_armature(None)
incorrect_pose_correct_bone_rotations = make_armature(mathutils.Quaternion((1.0, 0.0, 0.0), math.radians(90.0)))

pose(correct_pose_incorrect_bone_rotations)
pose(incorrect_pose_correct_bone_rotations)
```


Try pose_bone.rotation_quaternion = imported_rotation_quaternion.conjugated() @ imported_keyframe_quaternion. See also this.

Thank you for replying. This was one of the first things I tried and it doesn't seem to work. I don't understand what the issue is because I thought it was this simple and that code does seem to be explaining the same problem.

Hm. I believe edit_bone.matrix is the transform to armature space, so that means your imported_rotation_quaternion is relative to the armature? The formula I gave needs everything relative to the parent. Is imported_keyframe_quaternion relative to the parent or to the armature?

Yeah they're relative to the armature. I've tried to use this instead pose_bone.rotation_quaternion = (pose_bone.parent.bone.matrix_local.to_quaternion().inverted() @ pose_bone.bone.matrix_local.to_quaternion()).inverted @ imported_keyframe_quaternion but that isn't working either.

I don't know if it helps but i've added an example script to the question.

I think i've fixed this. The pose bones rotation must be calculated like this:
bone_rotation = pose_bone.bone.matrix_local.to_quaternion()

pose_bone.rotation_quaternion = (bone_rotation.inverted() @ imported_rotation_quaternion) @ bone_rotation

and the location must be calculated like this:
bone_rotation = pose_bone.bone.matrix_local.to_quaternion().to_matrix().to_4x4()

pose_bone.location = bone_rotation.inverted() @ imported_location_vector

It was the secondary multiply by the bone's rotation that was the missing part.
